# Unsupported Class Version during Maven build in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, java-7, jdk6

I've seen a few of these questions on here, but none of the solutions/tips seem to be pointing me in the right direction. So I have 3 JDK's installed in the locations of "/opt/java/6", "/opt/java/7", and "/opt/java/8". All of these are set in the global Jenkins configuration. Jenkins itself is run using Java 8 which is the system default JRE that I set manually through alternatives (I'm using CentOS 7). I had a bunch of old projects that are built using maven and the maven compiler plugin which is set to source=1.6 target=1.6 . Every time I try to execute a build with the Java 6 JDK I get

> `Started by user Antony Prince`
>   `ln builds/lastSuccessfulBuild /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BitCalculator/lastSuccessful failed`
>   `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BitCalculator/lastSuccessful`
>   `at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)`
>   `at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)`
>   `at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)`
>   `at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)`
>   `at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
>   `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)`
>   `at hudson.Util.createSymlinkJava7(Util.java:1194)`
>   `at hudson.Util.createSymlink(Util.java:1112)`
>   `at hudson.model.Run.createSymlink(Run.java:1851)`
>   `at hudson.model.Run.updateSymlinks(Run.java:1832)`
>   `at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1743)`
>   `at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)`
>   `at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)`
>   `at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)`
>   `ln builds/lastStableBuild /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BitCalculator/lastStable failed`
>   `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/BitCalculator/lastStable`
>   `at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)`
>   `at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)`
>   `at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)`
>   `at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)`
>   `at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
>   `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)`
>   `at hudson.Util.createSymlinkJava7(Util.java:1194)`
>   `at hudson.Util.createSymlink(Util.java:1112)`
>   `at hudson.model.Run.createSymlink(Run.java:1851)`
>   `at hudson.model.Run.updateSymlinks(Run.java:1833)`
>   `at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1743)`
>   `at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)`
>   `at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)`
>   `at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)`
>   `Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BitCalculator`
>   `> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10`
>   `Fetching changes from the remote Git repository`
>   `> git config remote.origin.url /home/git/repositories/java/BitCalculator.git # timeout=10`
>   `Fetching upstream changes from /home/git/repositories/java/BitCalculator.git`
>   `> git --version # timeout=10`
>   `> git fetch --tags --progress /home/git/repositories/java/BitCalculator.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
>   `> git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10`
>   `Checking out Revision 4f119f7783cc4ff00e5bf9bb27850ae7698d4fe8 (origin/master)`
>   `> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10`
>   `> git checkout -f 4f119f7783cc4ff00e5bf9bb27850ae7698d4fe8`
>   `> git rev-list 4f119f7783cc4ff00e5bf9bb27850ae7698d4fe8 # timeout=10`
>   `Parsing POMs`
>   `[BitCalculator] $ /opt/java/6/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.5.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/share/maven /var/lib/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.44.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.5.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 56445`
>   `<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started`
>   `Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BitCalculator/pom.xml -P sign clean deploy`
>   `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)`
>   `at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)`
>   `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:331)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)`
>   `at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)`
>   `at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)`
>   `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)`
>   `at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)`
>   `at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)`
>   `at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`
>   `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/inject/Provider : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`
>   `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`
>   `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)`
>   `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)`
>   `at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)`
>   `at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)`
>   `at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:86)`
>   `... 22 more`
>   `channel stopped`
>   `[BitCalculator] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6524656470722686910.sh`
>   `+ rm 'target/*no_deps*'`
>   `rm: cannot remove 'target/*no_deps*': No such file or directory`
>   `Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`
>   `ERROR: Failed to parse POMs`
>   `hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
>   `at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:178)`
>   `at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)`
>   `at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)`
>   `at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)`
>   `at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`
>   `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)`
>   `at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)`
>   `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)`
>   `at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)`
>   `... 10 more`
>   `Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
>   `at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)`
>   `... 15 more`
>   `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
>   `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)`
>   `at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)`
>   `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:331)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)`
>   `at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)`
>   `... 15 more`
>   `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/inject/Provider : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`
>   `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`
>   `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)`
>   `at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)`
>   `at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)`
>   `at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)`
>   `at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:386)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)`
>   `at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)`
>   `at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:86)`
>   `... 22 more`
>   `Archiving artifacts`
>   `Sending e-mails to: antony@blazrsoft.com`
>   `Finished: FAILURE`

This indicates that there's Java 7 interfering somewhere, but I'm not sure where.
The code is 1.6 compliant and most of the projects have no dependencies, so I'm not sure why this is happening. If I execute maven outside of Jenkins, the projects build just fine with JDK 6, so its leading me to think there's a misconfiguration in Jenkins somewhere, but I'm not sure where since everything seems to be as it should be. The paths to the JDKs are set properly in the global config and the projects themselves are set to use the specified JDK's. I apologize if its a duplicate question or something silly, but I've been trying to figure this out for days with no results. Everyone just says to check the paths and make sure there are no dependent artifacts built with a later JDK and I'm sure that this is not the problem.

`$ mvn -version`
`Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-16)`
`Maven home: /usr/share/maven`
`Java version: 1.8.0_20, vendor: Oracle Corporation`
`Java home: /opt/java/8/jre`
`Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968`
`OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

`<plugin>`
`<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>`
`<version>3.1</version>`
`<configuration>`
`<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>`
`<source>1.6</source>`
`<target>1.6</target>`
`<compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>`
`</configuration>`
`</plugin>`

Comment: When you run on the command line, do you run with the same user with which Jenkins runs? If not, please paste the output of $PATH from both command line and from Jenkins console output (`echo $PATH` just before the step where the compilation starts).

Comment: Show full output of the error message and not only an excerpt. Which Maven version do you use and which version of the maven-compiler-plugin do you use?

Comment: Added full error log from Jenkins, maven version info, and maven compiler plugin version.

Comment: I'll add the info for which user it is successful as a bit later. Updated my Sonatype Nexus repository and deleted all my artifacts because they changed the directory structure a few versions back and I failed to update my script for updating Nexus, so the sonatype-work directory was lost. Have a few artifacts I need to redeploy for the build to succeed. Currently jenkins is running as "git". It used to run as "jenkins", but recently I started having problems accessing local repositories even though I had the credentials saved in Jenkins. Lots of problems cropping up recently it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You have an old java version. For example in my case I´m compiling an old product so I have to keep the java deprecated version.
So the solution was to download a newest jdk and configure the JAVA_HOME in the slave.
http://lmarccdk12.ptx.fr.sopra:14000/computer//configure in the section Advanced/JavaPath=/root/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java  (that´s the version I chose)

You will see the following message in the slave launch log:
[SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/root" && /root/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java  -jar slave.jar

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins job is of type "Maven project", and this job type has a limitation in that it cannot run a Maven build with a JDK version that is older than the Java version under which Jenkins is run.

Beginning with Jenkins 2.357 (released on June 28, 2022) and the forthcoming 2.361.1 LTS release, Jenkins requires Java 11 or newer. Therefore, you can no longer run Maven projects with JDKs 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8. The minimum version is now Java 11.

To resolve this, you may:

- Create a Freestyle project and use *Invoke top-level Maven targets* to invoke Maven, or create a Jenkins Pipeline project. In both cases, using an older JDK will be possible.
- Use JDK 11 but set source and target version to the older Java version. I haven't tried that though, and I believe this option may cause other trouble.

For further information, see also [Jenkins requires Java 11 or newer](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/06/28/require-java-11/) and [Maven Builds Fails After Upgrade](https://community.jenkins.io/t/maven-builds-fails-after-upgrade/3850/2)